# Convert a mobi file to pdf file

Tags: pdf, mobi

I have a mobi file, and want to convert it to a pdf file. I tried several online conversion websites, but couldn't convert it. Can you help me? Thanks! Here is [a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/Mary_W._Cornog_Merriam-Websters_Vocabulary_Builder____2010.mobi) to the mobi file.

Comment: Which solutions have you tried already? It's important to know that, because otherwise, we will maybe recommend you solutions which you've already tried.

Comment: @c0dev: Top three websites I googled "convert mobile to pdf", including http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf

Comment: Thx for the additional information. On which operating system are you? windows, linux or mac?

Comment: linux... @c0dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you, to use the tool [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). It's a free converter for ebooks.

> Calibre is a tool to convert and manage ebooks.
> *Screenshot from convert-interface*
>
> [image]

[Download](http://calibre-ebook.com/download)